# send login data with POST method in a universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working a windows app store,and I am trying to send login and password values,this is my code:

```
 try
        {
            string user = login.Text;
            string pass = password.Password;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "login=" + user + "&mdp=" + pass;
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myURL/login.php");
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Dispose();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);


            sr.Dispose();
            stream.Dispose();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

I have many errors like this:

```
'WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content Length' and no extension method 'ContentLength' accepting a first argument of type 'WebRequest' was found (a using directive or an assembly reference is she missing ?)
'WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequestStream' and no extension method 'GetRequestStream' accepting a first argument of type 'WebRequest' was found (a using directive or an assembly reference is she missing? )
'WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first argument of type 'WebRequest' was found (a using directive or an assembly reference is she missing? )
```

I am new in universal windows Apps,so have you please any idea how can I correct my code to send login data to the server
thanks for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have noticed, [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET Core is a little bit different than traditional .NET. First of all, I suggest you to look at the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient) class which is the default class in UWP for working with HTTP.

If you want to go with the WebRequest, in order to set Content-Length header, use the Headers property:

```
request.Headers["ContentLength"] = length;
```

In order to get request and response streams, you need to use the [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) method, GetRequestStreamAsync and GetResponseAsync. Synchronous methods are not available.

Your code will look like this after all:

```
string user = login.Text;
string user = login.Text;
string pass = password.Password;

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "login=" + user + "&mdp=" + pass;
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("myURL/login.php");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Headers["ContentLength"] = data.Length.ToString();

using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()) {
   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) {
   using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream)) {
         //
     }
   }
}
```