# Windows-Universal https Post Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, https, xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I want to make a Json Post Request with my Windows Universal App.
I have it working in my Android and IOS.

```
   public String DoServiceCall()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{2}/{0}/{0}ServiceJson.svc/{1}", "Authentication", "Authenticate", "https://....."));

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // create the request object
            string requestString = JSONRequest;
            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            // add known cookies to request (needed for authentication)
            CookieContainer requestCookies = new CookieContainer();
            foreach (Cookie knownCookie in this._cookieCollection)
            {
                requestCookies.Add( knownCookie);
            }
            request.CookieContainer = requestCookies;

            //For getting rid of the https Problem
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            using (Stream stream =  request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
            }
            // get response data
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return (responseString);
        }
    }
```

The Problem is that Windows Universal does not support.

```
request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
requestCookies.Add( knownCookie); //with only one Argument
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Neither does it support.

```
request.GetRequestStream())
(HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

But that i could fix with async

```
await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
(HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

But without that 4 Lines i couldn´t get it working on Windows.
I just doesn´t get any Response.
Is there an Option to get it working on Windows 10 or is there an Working alternative.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35273153/3956290) answer.

Comment: Tried it, still didn´t got any anwser. I think i might be a problem with the custom SSL Zertifikat.

Comment: You didn't, Check the HttpClient class, it does all you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally found a solution.
Based on the Comment i tried the HttpClient.
But the Stanard Httpclient in the system namespace doesn`t support filter, which i need to get pass the SSL certificat problem.
Luckly in the Windows.Web.Http namespace, there is another HttpClient, which suppports filters. 
The answer is the fully functional HttpClient Post Call.

```
public async void testcallwind()
    {
        List<HttpCookie> cookieCollection = new List<HttpCookie>();
        HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        HttpClient httpClient;
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);//Allow untrusted CA's 
        filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
        // add known cookies to request (needed for authentication)
        foreach (HttpCookie knownCookie in cookieCollection)
        {
            filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(knownCookie);
        }
        httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
        string resourceAddress = string.Format("https://...");
        string requestString = "{\"request\":{\"CallerState\":null,...."}}";
        byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);        
        UnicodeEncoding en = new UnicodeEncoding();

        IHttpContent content = new HttpStringContent(requestString, 0, "application/json");
        Uri postBody = new Uri(resourceAddress);            

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(postBody, content);
        httpClient.Dispose();
        var test = response.Content;
    }
```