# Login to a WebSite in Universal App don't work

Tags: c#, universal

I have this code:

```
public async Task<string> getData()
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = string.Format("school={0}&username={1}&password={2}", "schoolcode", "username", "password");
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/login");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers["ContentLength"] = data.Length.ToString();
        Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string res = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return res;
    }
```

when i execute the code it stay on the line:

```
Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
```

forever and it don't work, i have tried this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272377/send-login-data-with-post-method-in-a-universal-app) but for me it don't work, does anyone know why? Thanks ;)

I also tried to change the url with www.google.com but it don't work neither. I don't have any proxy.

Comment: Is the API you're using your own, or a 3rd party one? *If it's your own, are you able to test to see if the request actually gets there?* Do you have any exceptions bubble up and get handled by higher up `try`/`catch` blocks?

Comment: at the moment i can't check that, but i don't get any crash

Comment: OK. So is it your own API? And that's good that it doesn't crash: do you have any calls to this method (or before that) wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block? You could always try setting the request's timeout to something small like 10 seconds to see if an exception is thrown