# How Could I Use Contentlength, GetResponse, or GetRequestStream In A UWP App (C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, httpwebrequest

I know C# but am new to UWP... I have noticed that some `HttpWebRequest` definitions are non existent in UWP. How would I be able to use `ContentLength`, `GetRequestStream`, and `GetResponse` in a UWP application? Thanks. Here is my code if needed:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SelectedItem + url);
webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", SOAPACTION);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContinueTimeout = 2000;
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

string postData = xmlData;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Dispose();

WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Dispose();
response.Dispose();
return responseFromServer;
```

Comment: See [Send login data with POST method in a universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272377/send-login-data-with-post-method-in-a-universal-app/35273153#35273153), it's a similar question.

Comment: the answer required quite a bit of modifying but i got it to work. Thanks :)

Comment: You can write an answer to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it as accepted. So that others who have the same problem can find the answer easily.